# Couldn't load file: assets

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, tiled

I am trying to render a Tiled Map on Eclipse libGDX. Here is my code that renders the map. This is an assignment for my school. I really need help. It keeps saying the file cant be found!

```
package screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class Play implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer otmr;

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        otmr.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float arg0) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        otmr.render();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("assets/level1.1.tmx");

        otmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    }

}
```

This is the text of the tmx level file. The text that comes up when u right click level1.1.tmx and click open with/text editor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.2" tiledversion="1.3.1" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" compressionlevel="0" width="62" height="37" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" infinite="0" nextlayerid="4" nextobjectid="1">
 <editorsettings>
  <export target="." format="csv"/>
 </editorsettings>
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="prTiles.tsx"/>
 <layer id="2" name="Tile Layer 2" width="62" height="37">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,4,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,5,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,7,7,7,5,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,6,7,6,7,7,7,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,6,6,6,2,6,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,5,5,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,2,2,2,2,2,2,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

This is the text for the TileSet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset version="1.2" tiledversion="1.3.1" name="prTiles" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" tilecount="10" columns="10">
 <image source="prTiles.tsx" width="160" height="16"/>
</tileset>
```

Here is the error

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3 (file:/D:/Downloads/libGDX/libGDX/gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: assets
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:96)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:84)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
    at screens.Play.show(Play.java:57)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at PrisonRevelations.create(PrisonRevelations.java:10)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Cannot open a stream to a directory: assets (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets (Access is denied)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:155)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:140)
    ... 12 more
```

Please help!!!!

Comment: Where did you copy that level1.1.tmx file exactly? Is it inside android project?

Comment: I made it on Tiled. I do not have an Andriod folder

Comment: For LibGDX all asset files (pictures, sounds, maps..) must be in "assets" folder of "android" project, as far as I know.

Comment: Actuall, my bad - all my projects have Android sub-project, but that doesn't have to be the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721143/how-to-set-assets-folder-of-libgdx-without-creating-an-android-project

Comment: I didn't use android though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your setup:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3 (file:/D:/Downloads/libGDX/libGDX/gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
```

Probably is not affecting you right now, but this means that you need to use JDK 8 https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4927

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets (Access is denied)
```

Here it throws this exception since it can't find the assets folder.
It should work by default as long as the assets folder is in your project, but try to use an absolute path first and see if it works.

e.g:

```
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("D:/assets/level1.1.tmx");
```

On another note if it's an android project have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135949/8794926

Comment: If I get JDK 8, how do I connect it with Eclipse?

Comment: @KeyFive check it out here [setting-jdk-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)